# How can I migrate a SQL Server 2008 Express database to SQL Server 2008 Standard?

Tags: sql-server-2008

SharePoint 2010 automatically installed the database on SQL Server Express 2008 but I need to migrate the database to SQL Server 2008. How can I go about doing this?

This is installed on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backup and restore or detach and re-attach are the two easiest methods.

Comment: Short and concise, just the way we like it!

Comment: Details are available if needed. ;)

Comment: Would you mind linking to or providing the steps for one of these (either is fine)? I appreciate it joe...amazing how many answers you have!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187858.aspx + http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187048.aspx

Comment: Glad to help...